# Why is this block-container forcing a second page?

Tags: svg, xsl-fo

I have an XSL-FO stylesheet that has inside of it an SVG that is the size of the entire page. I'm trying to absolutely position an image on top of the SVG. When I add that image, a second page is forced onto the PDF output. Without either the block or the SVG, there is only one page. Here's the code:

```
<xsl:template match="MyTag"> 
  <fo:block>
    <fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" top="110px" left="557px" height="185px" width="160px">
      <fo:block>
        <fo:external-graphic>
          <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="Image"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:attribute name="content-height">185px</xsl:attribute>
        </fo:external-graphic>
      </fo:block>
    </fo:block-container>
    <fo:instream-foreign-object>
      <svg>
        <!-- The full page sized SVG created by Inkscape here -->
      </svg>
    </fo:instream-foreigh-object>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Any ideas what I would have done wrong here that's forcing that second blank page? My understanding was that if something is absolutely positioned, it shouldn't affect the flow of the elements, but it seems to here.

For what it's worth, I originally tried to put the image as an `<image>` tag inside of the SVG, but it never showed up, I'm unsure if it's a problem with the pdf renderer (IBEX) or some other issue, so I'm trying to do this to work around it.

Comment: I don't think that XSL-FO is relevant here. Providing the SVG that is created will probably help more.

Comment: The SVG element is 1400 lines. Seems like more information that is interesting. Is there some piece(s) of it that would be helpful?

Comment: My feeling is also that it it would likely be simpler to add the image directly to the SVG file. You should add it at the end of the file, so that it has a higher z-index than all of the other elements. Perhaps create a reduced example of an SVG file with JUST this image, and see if your SVG renderer will render that. You might also compare the rendering of the IBEX renderer with alternate renderers, including those that have better tool support. For example, Chrome includes Webkit's web inspector, which allows you to mouse over elements in the DOM, which will graphically highlight their bbox.

Comment: I discovered that the version of IBEX we use is what isn't supporting the `<image>` tag inside of the SVG (works fine in the most recent). Upgrading all of our customers isn't trivial for a variety of reasons, which means I'd still like to get my work around to work. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work around. Basically, I altered the block that contained the `<svg>` thusly:

```
<fo:block-container absolute-position="absolute" height="5in">
    <fo:block>
        <fo:instream-foreign-object>
            <svg>
                <!-- The full page sized SVG created by Inkscape here -->
            </svg>
        </fo:instream-foreigh-object>
    </fo:block>
</fo:block-container>
```

Since the block is absolutely positioned, the full page sized SVG is allowed to flow outside of its 5in block, but it tricks the layout manager into thinking it has enough space for the image and the SVG on a single page (which it does).